# python: does `for i in obj.func()` re-run `func` every iteration?

Tags: python, optimization, loops, for-loop

let's say I have the following code:

```
for a in object.a_really_huge_function():
    print a
```

In order to prevent `a_really_huge_function` from running multiple times, I am used to doing this in other languages:

```
a_list = object.a_really_huge_function()
for a in a_list:
    print a
```

Is that necessary in Python? Will the part after `in` run on every single loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The python interpreter is your friend.

```
>>> def some_func():
...     print 'in some_func'
...     return [1, 2, 3, 10]
... 
>>> for a in some_func():
...     print a
... 
in some_func
1
2
3
10
```

In short, no, it gets called once.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use generators to avoid returning huge results by relinquishing control after each step of the algorithm as follows:

```
def a_really_huge_fuction(huge_number):
    i = 0
    while i < huge_number:
        yield i   # Relinquishes control to caller, resume execution at next line
        i = i + 1
```

In this case, the function is called once, but has its execution spread over `huge_number` different times. See the [yield](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) documentation for more details.

Comment: The question was does `a_really_huge_fuction` get called more than once.  This answer doesn't address that, so why the upvotes?

Comment: I've clarified than answer. In the case of generators, the function is called once bu is executed in phases.

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary.

```
for a in object.a_really_huge_function():
```

calls  `a_really_huge_function` only once.

The only advantage of saving the result in a variable would be if you are calling the same function elsewhere in your code.

If the function returns a list, you might do better in terms of memory usage by making `object.a_really_huge_function()` return an [iterator](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pycon.html), but otherwise you are fine.